# When does adding conditionals becomes too much in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, conditional-statements

This question uses React Native as an example, but can apply to React in general.

Given a FlatList component that renders different lists depending on which list the user has chosen, when does adding conditionals for a specific list within that component become too much?

For example, adding this throughout the component just to get behavior for that specific list:

```
if (this.props.list = 'groceryList') {
  do this...
}
```

This check can be in `ComponentDidMount` `ComponentDidUpdate` calling other functions and doing lengthy calculations that are only related to the "groceryList".

Is it better practice to just create a component only for this list since it is adding these checks and adding convolution?  It feels almost like writing a component inside a component and not using the component as it was originally intended.

Comment: "...almost like writing a component inside a component..." Like component composition? The very pattern react recommends and works well with? Sure! Can you share some actual component code, and what (if anything) isn't working? Basically, determine if there's an issue to fix in the first place. Things like, poor performance, unreadable code, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditionals inside the components, a parent component, and depending on the list type render each type of children component. Thats totally a good pattern.

```
   function Greeting(props) {
      const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        return <UserGreeting />;
      }
      return <GuestGreeting />;
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      // Try changing to isLoggedIn={true}:
      <Greeting isLoggedIn={false} />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Also you can use the inline conditional operator, or logical operators inside render method.

```
    render() {
      const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
      return (
        <div>
          {isLoggedIn
            ? <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
            : <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
```

the pattern is called conditional rendering. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

https://reactpatterns.com/ [ search for conditional rendering section ]